# Android Bluetooth from within Service

Tags: android, service, bluetooth

I have a service that theoretically can work without an Activity associated to it (as "services" are intended on the Android platform).

This service uses Bluetooth, in particular registers a Bluetooth Service with a given Name that listens for communications. Of course to work it has to have the Bluetooth active.

As also shown on the Bluetooth api docs I'm using the `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE` to prompt the user to enable Bluetooth in case it's not on already. This, though, is an activity, and therefore needs to be called from another activity, i.e.:

```
Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
InstanceOfAnActivity.startActivity(enableIntent);
```

What I would want to achieve is to have the service (which, for example, starts up at boot), completely decoupled from any Activity, and therefore wouldn't have the `InstanceOfAnActivity` to start up the pop-up instructing the user to turn on Bluetooth.

Now, I know that there's the (infamous) call to `BluetoothAdapter.enable()`, but as the doc says it shouldn't be called directly.

So, any tip/solution to this dilemma? (Maybe it's easy and I'm just missing something...)

Comment: It's a few months later now and I'm wondering if you were able to overcome this issue?

Comment: How do "Beautiful widgets" to turn on bluetooth without user permission ?

Answer (score 5):

`startActivity()` is not strictly an Activity method - it is a Context method, inherited by Activity *and* Service.
There is one thing to be aware of, though - as pointed out in the `Service.startActivity()` doc, "if this method is being called from outside of an Activity Context, then the Intent must include the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` launch flag".

Thus, with 'context' bound to the Service instance, the following should work:

```
Intent btIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
btIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(btIntent);
```

Comment: How can I handle the result of activity?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the doc says

> **Bluetooth should never be enabled without direct user consent.** If you want to turn on Bluetooth in order to create a wireless connection, you should use the ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE Intent, which will raise a dialog that requests user permission to turn on Bluetooth. The enable() method is provided only for applications that include a user interface for changing system settings, such as a "power manager" app.

Note that it doesn't say **not** to call `BluetoothAdapter.enable()` directly, it says only to call it if you've gotten the ok from the user.  That means that you would need a configuration screen that asked the user if it was ok for your service to turn on bluetooth and that way they could have the control over that.

Comment: The questions asks if it is possible to ask the user to turn on bluetooth, and then handle the result, outwith the context of an activity specifically created to handle that.